# How to initialize a Swift ViewController that has a non optional property passed from the preceding ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, optional-arguments

How does one initialize a Swift ViewController that has a non optional property passed from the preceding ViewController?

Please assume:

That all viewControllers are connected in the mainStoryboard and that the non-optional property is set to the childViewController in the prepareForSegue method of the parent.

```
class ParentVC{
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "playlistsSegue" {
            let vc = (segue.destination as! PlaylistsVC)
            vc.set = attachedSet
            vc.title = attachedSet?.name
        }
    }
}
```

The set property should be non optional because the ChildVC can't do it's thing without this model object. I have it working with the property in question as an optional and this led to a bug that took some time to isolate. By forcing this property to be set as part of the initialization trouble can be avoided now and in the future because the segue pattern shows up all the time.

```
class ChildVC{
var set:ModelObject 
}
```

Comment: You can't use your own initializer when using storyboards, so you won't be able to make the property non-optional.  I usually make them implicitly unwrapped optionals and add an `assert(object != nil)` to `viewDidLoad` so you will be able to tell immediately if you forget to set it before presenting the view controller.

Comment: Doesn't implicitly unwrapped optionals work? Admittedly, it crashes the program instead of showing a compile error, but it should tell you that it has a nil value.

Comment: Yes, just declare it as `var set: ModelObject!`

Comment: Declaring `var set: ModelObject!` will give you the non-optional property. While letting set the property on your own. But warning, if you use the property before setting it (Which is unlikely seeing as you're setting in `prepareForSegue:` your program will crash! So doing an assert like @dan suggested will be a safe test to make sure you set your variable before using it.

Comment: Using "set" as a property name is a terrible idea. Thanks the for the valuable discussion everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring `var set: ModelObject!` will give you the non-optional property. While letting set the property on your own. But warning, if you use the property before setting it (Which is unlikely seeing as you're setting in prepareForSegue: your program will crash! So doing an assert like @dan suggested will be a safe test to make sure you set your variable before using it.

```
class ChildVC{
     var set:ModelObject!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        assert(set != nil)

     }

}
```

Then you can just keep your code in `prepareForSegue:` in the `ParentVC` The same.

Comment: @Paulw11 prepareForSegue is called before `viewDidLoad()`. Perhaps you are thinking of `init()`? ViewController life cycle methods are not called until after instantiation and after a `UINavigationController` or `UIViewController` present/push the new `UIViewController` onto the navigation stack. Which to my understanding `prepareForSegue` is called before the vc is pushed onto a navigation stack. I use `viewDidLoad` because often I want to use that implicitly unwrapped optional in other calculations in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: And perhaps its not efficient to `assert` in `viewWillAppear` since it will be called multiple times in the VC's lifecycle.

Comment: I'm trying to look through apple's documentation right now to see if there is any clarification. But from my personal experience implicitly unwrapped optionals set in `prepareForSegue` have never been an issue in `viewDidLoad` but perhaps there can be issues in different kinds of segues that aren't push segues (segues I typically use).